# Solution(s) for the largest remainder?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, optimization

I have reached the following argument of the maximum problem:

$$ \hat{x} = \mathop{\arg\,\max}\limits_x \, \rm (n\ mod\ x), \quad \text{for $1 \le x \le n$, where $x,n \in \mathbb{N}^{+}$.}$$

My question is in regards the possible solution(s):

- Is there only one solution for all integers $n$?
- Does a general closed form expression for $\hat{x}$ exist (i.e., the largest remainder)?
- What can be said about $\hat{x}$ in general? Is $(\hat{x} - \rm (n\ mod\ \hat{x})) > 0$ generally (and trivially) true for all $n$?

My research efforts got me reading about the [Largest Remainder Methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_remainder_method). The problem I am facing, is to find $k \le n$ integers $n_1, n_2, \dots, n_k$, such that these are of similar size and sum to $n$. In general, when $\rm (n\ mod\ k) \neq 0$, I have the problem of distributing the remainder onto the $k$ integers - or live with a weird $n_{k+1}$.

Comment: Let's see if I interpret it correctly. For a given $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$, you are looking for the $x\in\mathbb{N}$ with $1\leqslant x \leqslant n$ such that "the least non-negative remainder of $n$ modulo $x$" becomes maximal?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, that sounds like a reasonable summary of my question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x > \frac{n}{2}$, the remainder of $n$ modulo $x$ is $n-x$, and that evidently attains its maximum if $x$ is chosen as small as possible subject to the condition $x > \frac{n}{2}$. That gives us $x = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor+1$ with the remainder $n - \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor - 1 = \left\lceil \frac{n}{2}\right\rceil - 1 = \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor$.

If $x \leqslant \frac{n}{2}$, since the remainder modulo $x$ is strictly smaller than $x$, the maximal possible remainder would be $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor - 1 = \left\lfloor \frac{n-2}{2}\right\rfloor$. That bound is strictly smaller than the value $\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor$ for odd $n$, and for even $n$, only $x = \frac{n}{2}$ makes that bound reachable at all, but then $n \equiv 0 \pmod{x}$, so we have the unique maximal remainder for

$$\hat{x} = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor + 1$$

with the value $\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor$.

Comment: Thanks. This overview was very helpful. Let me see if I understand it correctly. You analyze both halves of the range, and says that the bound for $x \le n/2$ is smaller than the bound for $x > n/2$, which makes the $x > n/2$ bound the unique maximal remainder in the entire range $1 \le x \le n$? It makes sense, I just to want to make sure that I understand it correctly :-)

Comment: Yes. It's not only that the bound for $x\leqslant n/2$ is smaller than the _bound_ for $x > n/2$, it's also smaller than the largest value you get. Actually, if you look a bit closer, for $x \leqslant n/2$, you have a bound of $\approx n/3$, so there's a comfortable cushion (for $n$ large enough that $n/2$ is much greater than $n/3$, the difference is naturally small for small $n$).